# Two Canvas for single Bitmap/ImageView

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` which can be zoomed using the `PhotoView` library. On application start I read a JSON file containing different image elements and I create a `Canvas` on top of this `Bitmap` in `ImageView` and draw all these map/image locations on top of it.

However I now need to draw a pointer on top of this bitmap which indicates users location and orientation (which is received from magnetic sensors) the problem is with one canvas I would have to erase everything from it and redraw it all again when I need to reposition the cursor or change it's direction.

Are multiple canvases possible for single `Bitmap/ImageView` if not what's my best option here ?

Comment: try using document.createElement("canvas"), then getting it's context, rendering both canvases to it(using drawImage()). If you still don't get it, I'll make you a fiddle.

Comment: This is withing Java not JavaScript

Comment: Oops. Saw the canvas tag and just assumed.